# expand collapse swap background on click

Tags: css, background, onclick, swap

I need jquery, or css only if possible,to swap background of class to make expand collapse button.

```
<div class="parrent">
<div class="expand_collapse"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.expand_collapse{
background:url(/img/expand.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

On "parrent" click background should go between expand.png and collapse.png.

Thanx

Comment: Could you please edit your title so that it relates to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="action"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent .action {
    background:url(/img/expand.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.parent .action.collapse {
    background:url(/img/collapse.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".parent").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".action").toggleClass("collapse");
    });
});
```

**Link to example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/TPAXz/

Comment: i have tried your solution it does not work, any suggestions?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the action div has absolute position if that makes any difference

Comment: what im trying to do is replicate news.google.com expand collapse button that appears on hovering one of the articles.

Comment: The code is missing a `)` after the `document` object. Maybe, depending on the browser, you have to remove the .action from the second CSS rule: `.parent .action.collapse` becomes `.parent .collapse`. You can put a `!important` after the `background` attribute: `background:url(/img/collapse.png) 0 0 no-repeat !important;` to force the background to change. See this http://jsfiddle.net/aLPv5/

Comment: I've updated the answer to add the missing `)` and provide a link to a working implementation.  As to your question about absolute positioning, that wouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear that.  Would you mind marking this answer as correct?